# How to get Connection string of a cosmos DB created for table API in ARM template

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-cosmosdb-tables

I am trying to create a cosmos db account for table APIs and want to upload the connection string to a KV using ARM template.

I expect the connection string in this format:

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<<AccountName>>;AccountKey=<<Key>>;TableEndpoint=https://<<AccountName>>.table.cosmos.azure.com:443/;
```

I am using this:

```
[listConnectionStrings(resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts', parameters('globalCosmosDBName')), '2019-12-12').connectionStrings[0].connectionString]
```

But with the above I am getting a connections string like below:

```
AccountEndpoint=https://<<AccountName>>.documents.azure.com:443/;AccountKey==<<Key>>;
```

How can I get a connection string with the table endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our RP does not return the legacy table connection string format. It only has the format you have below.

I think the only way to do this is to use `concat` to build the string and use a combination of the `reference` and `listKeys` arm functions below.

```
"[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts/', parameters('globalCosmosDBName'))).documentEndpoint]"

"[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts', parameters('globalCosmosDBName')), '2020-04-01').primaryMasterKey]"
```

Here is the complete concat function.

```
“[concat(‘DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=’, [reference(resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts/', parameters('globalCosmosDBName'))).documentEndpoint], ‘;AccountKey=’, [listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts', parameters('globalCosmosDBName')), '2020-04-01').primaryMasterKey], ‘;TableEndpoint=https://’, [reference(resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts/', parameters('globalCosmosDBName'))).documentEndpoint], ‘.table.cosmos.azure.com:443/;’]”
```

Answer (score 0):

Same deal for Azure Bicep. Here's what works for me for constructing the Table connection string

```
@description('Resource group for the table account')
param table_account_resource_group string
@description('Cosmosdb Table account name')
param table_account_name string

resource cosmosdb_table_account 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts@2023-04-15' existing = {
  name: table_account_name
  scope: az.resourceGroup(table_account_resource_group)
}

var accountKey = cosmosdb_table_account.listKeys().primaryMasterKey
var tableEndpoint = replace(cosmosdb_table_account.properties.documentEndpoint, 'documents', 'table.cosmos')
var formattedConnectionString = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${table_account_name};AccountKey=${accountKey};TableEndpoint=${tableEndpoint};'
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**